# Using an unregistered company name

Tags: legal

If I want to release an App with a Company Name do I have to have that registered before I can use it?

I have checked and the name is not taken, so is it fine to just use a made up company name?

As a side note, I have made this game just as a hobby project, not looking to make any money from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately, no. You do not need to register your company name. That said, you might what to consider *if you should*. You should consider it from a development point of view, and from a legal point of view.

#### A developers point of view

You do not need to have the company name registered to publish an application; at least, not for Android. While you do have to provide a company name, this is mainly to identify your applications, in case another user posts an application with the exact same name.

#### A legal point of view

This is where things get tricky, especially so given that I am not a lawyer, and I am only vaguely familiar with business name registry in Australia. At the end of the day, nothing requires you to register the name, but it is not really yours unless you do so. If another individual registers the name, it becomes theirs. If they wish to stop you from operating under the same name that they would then own, they might have a case to do so.

---

Ultimately, it does not sound like you are concerned with the monetary implications, given that you are making the game as a hobby. If you have any concerns regarding legal ramification, I would ask over at [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/), or better yet, an actual business lawyer. If you are only concerned with being rejected when attempting to *publish* your application, you need not worry.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I will mark as answer although I know not to take your answer as gospel. You have pointed out that to be really sure best to discuss with a business lawyer.